# multiple selectors jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter, jquery-selectors

This:

```
$('input.people').attr('checked', false).filter('[name=toddS]').attr('checked', true);
```

will select a checkbox with the class of people and the name toddS while unchecking all of the other boxes.

How do I add another name to the filter?  I've tried several different combinations and nothing works.  This is what I have:

```
$('input.people').attr('checked', false).filter('[name=toddS], [name=gwenD]').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function into [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2), like this:

```
$('input.people').attr('checked', function() {
  return this.name == 'toddS' || this.name == 'gwenD';
});
```

If you need to add more later, you can use something that works for more values, for instance [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), like this:

```
$('input.people').attr('checked', function() {
  return $.inArray(this.name, ['toddS', 'gwenD']) != -1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  Now how do I uncheck Todd and Gwen when their position(s) are unchecked?

Comment: @sehummel65 - Can you clarify a bit? I'm not understanding the question...you want the reverse, or to uncheck everyone or...?

Answer (score 0):

You could [use a function there](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#using-filter-function) to select the ones you want only.

```
$('input.people')
   .removeAttr('checked')
   .filter(function() {
       return ($(this).attr('name') === 'toddS' || $(this).attr('name') === 'gwenD');
    })
    .attr('checked', 'checked');
```

I also used `removeAttr()` instead of setting it to `false`. I haven't checked what jQuery does by setting it to `false`, but from a HTML perspective, being unchecked should mean the absence of that attribute.