# Multiple selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to run this code:

```
$("input[value='OK'][value='Recrutar'][value='Criar'][id!='attack_name_btn']").click();
```

So, as you see, I'm trying to select a input that has a value equal to "OK" or "Recrutar" or "Criar" and they may not have an id called "attack_name_btn".

But it's not working.

I ckecked this too, [multiple selectors jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489809/multiple-selectors-jquery)

Comment: The syntax you're using combines the selectors as 'AND's only (and as such will likely never catch an object). I don't know how to do this in jquery but what you have is definitely not what you want.

Comment: Perhaps something like this would work: `$("input[value='OK'],input[value='Recrutar'],input[value='Criar']").filter("input[id!='attack_name_btn']")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is actually doing an 'and' not an 'or'. What you have is the [multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/), but what you want is the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and then [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the results of that.

Answer (score 3):

Use multiple selectors to get all objects that match any of them like this and then filter out the ones you don't want:

```
$("input[value='OK'], input[value='Recrutar'], input[value='Criar']".filter("[id!='attack_name_btn']").click();
```